# Best visa category: visiting family and friends or tourist visa for Portugal?

Tags: visas, portugal, nepal, new-delhi, vfs-global

I am an Erasmus scholar in Portugal, for a period of 5 months (one semester). I want my wife to apply for a one-month visit visa in June before I head home in July. We want to go to different places in Europe together as part of our honeymoon. As both categories are possible, I wanted to know which is the preferred one in terms of credibility and practicality?

Comment: Which both categories do you mean?

Comment: @neusser I think asker is talking about a tourist visa versus a family visit visa. I don't know if Portugal or Schengen actually have these categories though.

Comment: Does the Erasmus programme allow you to take 1 month touring when you're only there for 5 months total?

Comment: I could not find a "visiting family and friends" category. There is a visa for visiting Wife/Husband of a Portuguese citizen which obviously doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.